# Ajax Call - I need a Ajax call that will send table data to my PHP query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

```html
$client_number = $_POST['client_number'];
 $client_name = $_POST['client_name'];
 $service = $_POST['service'];
 $size = $_POST['size'];
 $volume = $_POST['volume'];
 $deliver_point = $_POST['deliver_point'];
 $port_orgin = $_POST['port_orgin'];
 $a_port_orgin = $_POST['a_port_orgin'];
 $road_freight = $_POST['road_freight'];
 $terms = $_POST['terms'];
 $competitor = $_POST['competitor'];
 $freight_speed = $_POST['freight_speed'];
 $report_comments = $_POST['report_comments'];
 $company_stage = $_POST['company_stage'];
 $meeting_rating = $_POST['meeting_rating'];
 $client_user_name = $_POST['client_user_name'];
 $client_user_status = $_POST['client_user_status'];
 $client_user_kids = $_POST['client_user_kids'];
 $client_user_hobbies = $_POST['client_user_hobbies'];
 $client_user_comments = $_POST['client_user_comments'];

 
      
 $query="INSERT INTO tobytemp.fcl_reports (client_number,client_name,service,size,volume,deliver_point,port_orgin,a_port_orgin,road_freight,terms,competitor,freight_speed,report_comments,company_stage,meeting_rating,client_user_name,client_user_status,client_user_kids,client_user_hobbies,client_user_comments)

 VALUES ('".$client_number."', '".$client_name."', '".$service."', '".$size."', '".$volume."', '".$deliver_point."', '".$port_orgin."', '".$a_port_orgin."', '".$road_freight."', '".$terms."', '".$competitor."', '".$freight_speed."', '".$report_comments."', '".$company_stage."', '".$meeting_rating."', '".$client_user_name."', '".$client_user_status."', '".$client_user_kids."', '".$client_user_hobbies."', '".$client_user_comments."');";
 
 $result = $dbLink->query($query);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sales App</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/scicon.gif"/>
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(
hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kreon:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- start plugins -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
   var pull   = $('#pull');
    menu   = $('nav ul');
    menuHeight = menu.height();
   $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    menu.slideToggle();
   });
   $(window).resize(function(){
          var w = $(window).width();
          if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
           menu.removeAttr('style');
          }
      });
  });
 </script>
 

 

<!----font-Awesome----->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!----font-Awesome----->
</head>
<body>
<div class="header_bg" id="home"><!-- start header -->
<div class="container">
 <div class="row header text-center specials">
  <div class="h_logo">
   <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="responsive"/></a>
  </div>
  <nav class="top-nav">
   <ul class="top-nav nav_list">
    <li><a href="fclclient.html">FCL Clients</a></li> 
    <li class="page-scroll"><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></li>
    <li class="logo page-scroll"><a title="hexa" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" class="responsive"/></a></li>
      <li class="page-scroll"><a href="clientreports.html">Reports</a></li>
    <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   <a href="#" id="pull"></a>
  </nav>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>



<div class="main_bg" id="about"><!-- start about us -->
<div class="container">
 <div class="row about">
  <div class="col-md-3 about_img">
   <!--<img src="images/captain.png" alt="" class="responsive"/>-->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 about_text">
  
  
   </br></br><h3>Client Reports</h3>
   <h4>FCL Profile Extras</h4></br>
   <button class="buttons" id="showr">Show Table</button></br><button class="buttons" id="hider">Hide Table</button>
   </br></br>
   
        
<script>

$( "#showr" ).click(function() {
  $( "#fcl_form_data-table" ).slideDown( 100 );
});

$( "#hider" ).click(function() {
  $( "#fcl_form_data-table" ).slideUp( 100 );
});
</script>
   
   
   

   <table id="fcl_form_data-table" style="display: none">
   <th>BROSWER DB ID</th>
   <th>client_number</th>
   <th>client_name</th>
   <th>service</th>
   <th>size</th>
   <th>volume</th>
   <th>deliver_point</th>
   <th>port_orgin</th>
   <th>a_port_orgin</th>
   <th>road_freight</th>
   <th>terms</th>
   <th>competitor</th>
   <th>freight_speed</th>
   <th>company_stage</th>
   <th>meeting_rating</th>
   <th>client_user_name</th>
   <th>client_user_status</th>
   <th>client_user_kids</th>
   <th>client_user_hobbies</th>
   <th>client_user_comments</th>
   <th>Upload</th>
       
   
   
   
   <tr id="fcl_form_data-head">
   
   <!-- Saved data will be put here :D -->
   
   </tr>
   </table>
   
   </br>
   
  <!-- start -->
  
<div class="footer_bg">
<div class="container">
 <div class="row footer">
  <div class="col-md-8 contact_left">
  
   <form id="fcl_form_data-form" >
     
    <div class = "qborder" style="bottom-margin:500px; width:95%;">
    
     <h4>Client Info</h4></br>
     
     <input type="text" name="client_number" placeholder="Client Number" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Client Number';}">
     
     <input type="text" name="client_name" placeholder="Client Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Client Name';}">
    </div>
    
   <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
     <div class="multi-fields">
     <div class="multi-field">
       
       <div class = "qborder" style="width:15%;">
       
        <h4>Shipping Info</h4></br>

        <select name='service'>
        <option value=''>Service - </option>
          <option value='Inport'>Inport</option>
          <option value='Export'>Export</option>
          <option value='Airfreight'>Airfreight</option>
          <option value='W/housing'>W/housing</option>
        </select>
        
        </br></br>
        
        <select name='size'>
        <option value=''>Size - </option>
          <option value='20'>20</option>
          <option value='40'>40</option>
          <option value='40'>40</option>
          <option value='HQ'>HQ</option>
          <option value='45'>45</option>
          <option value='LCL'>Exact</option>
        </select>
        
        </br></br>
        
        <select name='volume'>
        <option value=''>Volume - </option>
          <option value='Daily'>Daily</option>
          <option value='Weekly'>Weekly</option>
          <option value='Monthly'>Monthly</option>
          <option value='Yearly'>Yearly</option>
          <option value='Exact'>Exact</option>
        </select></br>
        
        <input type="text" name="deliver_point" placeholder="Deliver Point">
        
        <input type="text" name="port_orgin" placeholder="Port Origin">
        
        <input type="text" name="a_port_orgin" placeholder="A/Port Origin">
        
        <input type="text" name="road_freight" placeholder="Road Freight">
        
        <!-- onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Road Freight';}" -->
        
        <select name='terms'>
        <option value=''>Terms - </option>
          <option value='EXM'>EXM</option>
          <option value='FOB'>FOB</option>
          <option value='PrePaid'>PrePaid</option>
        </select>
       
        </br></br>
        
        <select name='competitor'>
        <option value=''>Competitor - </option>
          <option value='1'>1</option>
          <option value='2'>2</option>
          <option value='3'>3</option>
        </select></br>
        
        <input type="text" name="freight_speed" placeholder="Freight Speed"  onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Freight Speed';}">
        
        <textarea name="report_comments" placeholder="Comments"  onfocus="if(this.value == 'Comments') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value='Comments;"></textarea>
       
      <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
      
      <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>    
       
       </div>  
        </br>
       
        
     </div>   
     </div>
   </div>

    
    <div class = "qborder" style="width:95%;">
     <h4>Meeting Info</h4></br>   
     <select name='company_stage' >
     <option value=''>Company Stage - </option>
       <option value='1'>1</option>
       <option value='2'>2</option>
       <option value='3'>3</option>
       <option value='4'>4</option>
     </select>
     
     
      <select name='meeting_rating'>
     <option value=''>Meeting Rating - </option>
       <option value='1'>1</option>
       <option value='2'>2</option>
       <option value='3'>3</option>
       <option value='4'>4</option>
       <option value='5'>5</option>
     </select>
    
    </div>
    
     </br>

    <div class = "qborder" style="width:95%;">
    <h4> Personal Information </h4></br>
    
     <input type="text" name="client_user_name" placeholder="User Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}">
     
     <select name='client_user_name_status'>
     <option value=''>Status - </option>
       <option value='Single'>Single</option>
       <option value='Married'>Married</option>
     </select>
     
     <select name='client_user_name_kids'>
     <option value=''>Kids - </option>
       <option value='1'>1</option>
       <option value='2'>2</option>
       <option value='3'>3</option>
       <option value='4'>4</option>
       <option value='5'>5+</option>
     </select>
     
     <input type="text" name="client_user_name_hobbies"  onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Hobbies';}">
     
     
     <textarea name="client_user_comments" placeholder="Comments"  onfocus="if(this.value == 'Comments') this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value='Comments;"></textarea>
    </div>
    
    </br>
    <span class="pull-left">
    
    
    

    
     
    <!-- <input type="button" id="fcl_form_data-op-discard" value="Discard" /> -->
   
    <input type="submit" id="fcl_form_data-op-save" value="Save" />
    
    

    <input type="hidden" name="id_entry" value="0" />
    
    
    
    
    
    </span>
    <div class="clear"></div>
   </form>
  </div>
 
 </div>
</div>
</div>

 <!-- End -->
   
   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>




<div class="footer_bg" id="contact"><!-- start footer -->
<div class="container">
 <div class="row footer">
 


  <div class="col-md-4  contact_right">
   <!-- <p><span>About Us: </span> Established in 1998, The Cardinal Maritime Group is one of the fastest growing logistics service providers. </p> -->
   <ul class="list-unstyled address">
    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:sales@cardinalmaritime.com">sales@cardinalmaritime.com</a></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span>England Tel: +44 (0) 161 492 1778</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>Cardinal Maritime Limited, Leestone Road, Sharston Industrial Estate, Manchester M22 4RB </span></li>
   </ul>
  </div>  
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer1_bg"><!-- start footer1 -->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row  footer">
   <div class="copy text-center">
    <p class="link"><span>&#169; Cardinalmaritime | <a href="http://www.cardinalmaritime.com/"> Cardinal Maritime</a></span></p>
    <a href="#home" id="toTop" style="display: block;"><span id="toTopHover" style="opacity: 1;"> </span></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
  $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
   var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
   $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
    $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper).clone(true).appendTo($wrapper).find('input').val('').focus();
   });
   $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
    if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
     $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
   });
  });
   
 
</script>



<script>

var fcl_form_data = {
 index: window.localStorage.getItem("fcl_form_data:index"),
 $table: document.getElementById("fcl_form_data-table"),
 $form: document.getElementById("fcl_form_data-form"),
 $button_save: document.getElementById("fcl_form_data-op-save"),
 $button_discard: document.getElementById("fcl_form_data-op-discard"),
 init:
 function() {
   // initialize storage index
   if (!fcl_form_data.index) {
    window.localStorage.setItem("fcl_form_data:index", fcl_form_data.index = 1);
   }

  // initialize form
  fcl_form_data.$form.reset();
  
  /*
  fcl_form_data.$button_discard.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  fcl_form_data.$form.reset();
  fcl_form_data.$form.id_entry.value = 0;
  },
  true);
  */
  
  fcl_form_data.$form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  var entry = {
  id: parseInt(this.id_entry.value),
  client_number:this.client_number.value,
  client_name:this.client_name.value,
  service:this.service.value,
  size:this.size.value,
  volume:this.volume.value,
  deliver_point:this.deliver_point.value,
  port_orgin:this.port_orgin.value,
  a_port_orgin:this.a_port_orgin.value,
  road_freight:this.road_freight.value,
  terms:this.terms.value,
  competitor:this.competitor.value,
  freight_speed:this.freight_speed.value,
  report_comments:this.report_comments.value,
  company_stage:this.company_stage.value,
  client_user_name:this.client_user_name.value,
  client_user_name_status:this.client_user_name_status.value,
  client_user_name_kids:this.client_user_name_kids.value,
  client_user_name_hobbies:this.client_user_name_hobbies.value,
  client_user_comments:this.client_user_comments.value
  };
  
  if (entry.id == 0) { // add
  fcl_form_data.storeAdd(entry);
  // Adds data to table when pressed save - like a temp table above
  fcl_form_data.tableAdd(entry);
  }
  else { // edit
  fcl_form_data.storeEdit(entry);
  fcl_form_data.tableEdit(entry);
  }
  this.reset();
  this.id_entry.value = 0;
  event.preventDefault();
  },
  true);
  
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Load DB info into table 
  
  if (window.localStorage.length - 1) {
   var data_list = [], i, key;
   
   for (i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length; i++) {
    key = window.localStorage.key(i);
    if (/fcl_form_data:\d+/.test(key)) {
     data_list.push(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key)));
    }
   }
   if (data_list.length) {
    data_list
    .sort(
    function(a, b) {
    return a.id < b.id ? -1 : (a.id > b.id ? 1 : 0);
    })
    .forEach(fcl_form_data.tableAdd);
   }
  }
  
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  
  fcl_form_data.$table.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   var op = event.target.getAttribute("data-op");
   if (/edit|remove/.test(op)) {
    var entry = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("fcl_form_data:"+ event.target.getAttribute("data-id")));
      
    
    
    if (op == "edit") {
 
    fcl_form_data.$form.client_number.value = entry.client_number;
    fcl_form_data.$form.client_name.value = entry.client_name;
    fcl_form_data.$form.service.value = entry.service;
    fcl_form_data.$form.size.value = entry.size;
    fcl_form_data.$form.volume.value = entry.volume;
    fcl_form_data.$form.deliver_point.value = entry.deliver_point;
    fcl_form_data.$form.port_orgin.value = entry.port_orgin;
    fcl_form_data.$form.a_port_orgin.value = entry.a_port_orgin;
    fcl_form_data.$form.road_freight.value = entry.road_freight;
    fcl_form_data.$form.terms.value = entry.terms;
    fcl_form_data.$form.competitor.value = entry.competitor;
    fcl_form_data.$form.freight_speed.value = entry.freight_speed;
    fcl_form_data.$form.report_comments.value = entry.report_comments;
    fcl_form_data.$form.company_stage.value = entry.company_stage;
    fcl_form_data.$form.meeting_rating.value = entry.meeting_rating;
    fcl_form_data.$form.client_user_name.value = entry.client_user_name;
    fcl_form_data.$form.client_user_name_status.value = entry.client_user_name_status;
    fcl_form_data.$form.client_user_name_kids.value = entry.client_user_name_kids;
    fcl_form_data.$form.client_user_name_hobbies.value = entry.client_user_name_hobbies;
    fcl_form_data.$form.client_user_comments.value = entry.client_user_comments;
    fcl_form_data.$form.id_entry.value = entry.id;
    }
    else if (op == "remove") {
     if (confirm('Are you sure you want to remove "'+ entry.client_number +' '+ entry.client_name +'" from your fcl_form_data?')) {
     fcl_form_data.storeRemove(entry);
     fcl_form_data.tableRemove(entry);
     }
    }
    event.preventDefault();
   }
  },
  true);
 },
 storeAdd:
 function(entry) {
  entry.id = fcl_form_data.index;
  window.localStorage.setItem("fcl_form_data:index", ++fcl_form_data.index);
  window.localStorage.setItem("fcl_form_data:"+ entry.id, JSON.stringify(entry));
 },
 
 storeEdit:
 function(entry) {
  window.localStorage.setItem("fcl_form_data:"+ entry.id, JSON.stringify(entry));
 },
 
 storeRemove:
 function(entry) {
  window.localStorage.removeItem("fcl_form_data:"+ entry.id);
 },
 
 tableAdd:
 function(entry) {
 var $tr = document.createElement("tr"), $td, key;
 
  for (key in entry) {
   if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   $td = document.createElement("td");
   $td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry[key]));
   $tr.appendChild($td);
   }
  }
  
  $td = document.createElement("td");
  $td.innerHTML ='<a data-op="edit" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Edit</a> | <a data-op="remove" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Remove</a>';
  $tr.appendChild($td);
  $tr.setAttribute("id", "entry-"+ entry.id);
  fcl_form_data.$table.appendChild($tr);
 },
 tableEdit:
 function(entry) {
  var $tr = document.getElementById("entry-"+ entry.id), $td, key;
  $tr.innerHTML ="";
  
  for (key in entry) {
   if (entry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   $td = document.createElement("td");
   $td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry[key]));
   $tr.appendChild($td);
   }
  }
  $td = document.createElement("td");
  $td.innerHTML ='<a data-op="edit" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Edit</a> | <a data-op="remove" data-id="'+ entry.id +'">Remove</a>';
  $tr.appendChild($td);
 },
 tableRemove:
 function(entry) {
 fcl_form_data.$table.removeChild(document.getElementById("entry-"+ entry.id));
 }
};
fcl_form_data.init();
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

---

Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script, Here is my full script,

Comment: have you tried with ajax??

Comment: Show your Javascript code.

Comment: You don't like forms and regular posts?

Comment: @Buzinas added snippet of it TY

Comment: @JulioSoares I need it like this in-case there is no internet connection. Other wise Id just simply post to from a form to my php. It is going to be used for a phone gap application in the end.

Comment: What is the question or problem? What have you tried to resolve that problem.

Comment: You *really* need to separate your entities... and parameterize your query to avoid injection.

Comment: I need an ajax call, i dont know what to do. An ajax call that will take the data from the table that will be populated and sent to my php query. @charlietfl

Comment: You just pasted walls of code and you're asking for solutions that it seems you've already provided. If it isn't working, point out where's the problem exactly (*I made THIS, but instead of THAT, it outputed IT, and I need THIS*), and make an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @charlietfl Check the ajax attempt Iv added. Iv tried somthing along those lines

Comment: Shouldn't need to send whole table... just individual row data for CRUD operations. Datatables API makes data access quite easy and it is well documented

Comment: @AlanMachado It works I just need someone to show me how to write and ajax call that will take my table data and post it to my php/query file in the correct format. The format my php file is above.

Comment: You want people to write code for you, then? Because there are plenty of tutorials on that matter on the Internet, as well as complete docs covering the technology.

Comment: care to share me a link? @AlanMachado

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to start over your code, so you would be able to design it better, but as soon as it's already too big, and I don't have enough time for that, I'll keep your style, and try to help you:

First of all, you need to know that your PHP code will only handle `INSERT` statements, so, you'll need to do another code for the edits (`UPDATE` statement), and for the removals (`DELETE` statement).

You already have a `storeAdd` function, so I've copied to create the `databaseAdd` one:

```
databaseAdd: function(entry) {
  ajax('http://cmlsys/toby/fcl_form_upload.php', null, 'POST', entry);
},
```

And then, our `ajax` helper:

```
function ajax(url, callback, method, params) {
  if (!method) method = 'GET';

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url);

  if (callback) xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
    callback.call(this, xhr);
  });

  if (params) {
    params = Object.keys(params).map(function (key) {
      return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
    }).join('&');
    xhr.send(params);
  }
  else {
    xhr.send();
  }    
}
```

So you'll use right below the `storeAdd` and `tableAdd` functions:

```
if (entry.id == 0) { // add
  fcl_form_data.storeAdd(entry);
  // Adds data to table when pressed save - like a temp table above
  fcl_form_data.tableAdd(entry);
  fcl_form_data.databaseAdd(entry);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, is it possible to add a button so that it only runs ajax when clicked? Just so they can view/review whats in teh table before its added to the mysql database @buzinas

Comment: So I cant have 2 buttons? 1 to save to the browser and 1 to upload (run ajax)

Comment: if there is no internet connection it will save to the browser and not to the mysql db. So i need a submit button so it can be sent when the connection is being reestablished.

Comment: So, instead of calling the `databaseAdd` where I said, you can put it inside that button, but I don't know how your code is structured, so you must have a way to get the `entry` from somewhere.

Comment: I have just added my full script above instead of lots of snippets. Thank you again btw for your help. Im still getting my head round all of this. @buxinas

Comment: please dont give up on me :) @Buzinas

Comment: @rapidwaters if you want further help, create a [pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit) with your CSS, HTML, Javascript, etc. When it's fully working, I'll help you with the AJAX.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/i02hQy7jtUCvqPiVnnlT?p=catalogue @Buzinas There you go i have added my files and wrote a comment for you. Thankssss

Comment: @rapidwaters where is your css file?

Comment: Its on there now sorry @Buzinas

Comment: @rapidwaters here is your [plunker updated](http://plnkr.co/edit/4xYJoNSBa5zQSHUfvWqP?p=preview). I've created a new grid button 'Save to database', and another `else if` inside your event: `else if (op == "database") {
      fcl_form_data.databaseAdd(entry);
    }`. The `databaseAdd` code, and the `ajax` function are the same as the ones here in the answer.

Comment: Right it inserts into my database but there is no data just empty fields and no final alert saying "Client Report Complete" as it alerts in the php. @Buzinas

Comment: I've tested here, and it's sending the parameters as it should. `id=5&client_number=assasa&client_name=asasasa&service=&size=&volume=&deliver_point=&port_orgin=&a_port_orgin=&road_freight=&terms=&competitor=&freight_speed=&report_comments=&company_stage=2&client_user_name=12121&client_user_name_status=Married&client_user_name_kids=2&client_user_name_hobbies=asaa&client_user_comments=asasaasa1212121`

Comment: yea im getting that to. but blank entry's in the DB hmmmmm.

id=61&client_number=aaa&client_name=aaa&service=&size=&volume=&deliver_point=11&port_orgin=11&a_port_orgin=11&road_freight=11&terms=&competitor=&freight_speed=11&report_comments=111&company_stage=&client_user_name=&client_user_name_status=&client_user_name_kids=&client_user_name_hobbies=&client_user_comments=